# How do I get location for fancybox iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I am using Fancybox for my popups.  Whenever I create a new iframe, the iframe contains a page with links to other pages.  When the user clicks on different links in the iframe and closes the popup, I would like to get the last link that they have visited.

How can I retrieve the last visited link?  I can only get what I started with.

```
$.fancybox({
type: 'iframe',
href: 'https://slashdot.org/',
beforeClose: function() {
  alert('How do I get last link in the frame?');
  var name = $(this).prop("content")[0].name;
  var iframename = "Frame Name: " + name;
  var src = "Frame source: " + $('#' + name).attr('src');
  $('#output').html(iframename + "<br/>" + src);
 }
});
```

Sample code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jttmp/wgPTR/1813/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example that I provided was violating [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you have an IFrame that does not violate the Same-origin policy, then you can do the following to get the last link the user click on in the IFrame.

```
  $(".iframe_jump").fancybox({
  type: 'iframe',
  href: 'localFileWithLocalLinks.html',
  beforeClose: function() {
      // prop("content")[0] will retrieve a HTMLIFrameElement obj
      var iframe = $(this).prop("content")[0];
      try {
          // accessing 'contentWindow' property can trigger an error
          var url = iframe.contentWindow.document.location;
          var text = "Current window context location: " + url
          console.log(text);
      } catch(e) {
          // log any errors
          console.log(e);
      }
  }
```

});